# How can we return multiple SQL table in a single Postgres function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can we return multiple SQL table in a single Postgres function
I want something like this:

```
postgrefuction('some parameters')
RETURNS refcursor
...
...
...
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
...
...
...
BEGIN



SQL:='some queries';
SQL2:= 'some queries';
RETURN SQL,SQL2
$BODY$
```

Comment: what does this have to do with Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can return two `refcursor`s:

```
CREATE FUNCTION postgresfuction(
   IN param1 type1,
   IN param2 type2,
   ...,
   OUT result1 refcursor,
   OUT result2 refcursor
) RETURNS record LANGUAGE ... AS '...';
```